# Symfony2 - Defining boolean parameter in parameters.ini

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having problems to define a boolean parameter in `parameters.ini` file. This is the definition:

```
aParameter = true
```

Then, in `config.yml` I do:

```
aParameter: %aParameter%
```

But I'm getting this error:

> InvalidTypeException: Invalid type for path "myService.aParameter". Expected boolean, but got string.

This error disappears when I replace `%aParameter%` with `true`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code of `Configuration Class`(`getConfigTreeBuilder function` Where you are defining the configuration tree)?

Comment: Look at IniFileLoader class where ini files are loaded, there is no type casting. So everything will be string. You cant do nothing with this

Comment: Values in `ini` files will _always_ be strings. If you want other types of values you'll need to use another format, like `yaml` or `xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to achieve it. See [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2219). Simplest way is to replace your parameters.ini with parameters.yml

For example, [parameters.yml.dist](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/parameters.yml.dist) from symfony-standard

Comment: It's not that there is no way to achieve this. The point is that the current ini parser provided by sf2 don't support it. The easy way is of course to use yaml for example, but if you are stuck with ini files, you can take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Default Symfony2 import parameters in YAML format, so one of first line should be:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

And in parameters.yml use:

```
aParameter: true
```

I dont use INI files, so i dont know how it works.

Comment: Of course, I'm using `imports` and all other parameters work as strings. My only issue is trying to use a boolean parameter.

Comment: I am not sure.. but you write here aParameter = true, but in YAML which was default you should use aParameter: true (: not =).

If you are used import INI file, use 1 for true, 0 for false

Comment: Using `1` instead of `true` gives the same error. In `parameters.ini` definitions are with `=`, not `:`.

Comment: Symfony 2 use `parse_ini_file()` and by looking at this output : http://codepad.org/y16crlyi it seems that all types are not supported

Answer (score 3):

Symfony 2 uses [parse_ini_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-ini-file.php) function and it does not seem to return the right type for boolean value.

```
<?php

file_put_contents('test.ini', "test1=on\ntest2=true\ntest3=1");

var_dump(parse_ini_file('test.ini'));
```

will output

```
array(3) {
  'test1' => string(1) "1"
  'test2' => string(1) "1"
  'test3' => string(1) "1"
}
```

You might want to implement your own `ini` parser taking `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\IniFileLoader` as an example.

Example of lexer that supports booleans can be found in comments at php doc for [parse_ini_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-ini-file.php)

An alternative would be to use the yaml format for your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 3.4 you can "cast" them. See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables

```
parameters:
    # roughly equivalent to "(bool) getenv('BOOL_PARAM')"
    app.enable_something: '%env(bool:BOOL_PARAM)%'


bool:, int:, float: and string:
```